# List.contains in not working

Tags: apex, list

I have to get subset of users who do not have records in custom table last modified in last 15 minutes. Here is my code:

```
string query = 'Select Id FROM MyCustomObject__c where LastModifiedDate > ' + Datetime.now().addMinutes(15);

List<MyCustomObject__c> sobjList = Database.query(query);

List<String> userIdsToRemove = new List<String>();
for (MyCustomObject__c dataGrid :sobjList)
{
    userIdsToRemove.Add(dataGrid.Id);
}

List<User> allUsers = [select Id FROM User WHERE Profile.UserLicense.Name IN ('Salesforce','Salesforce Platform') AND 
                    IsActive=TRUE];
for (User u :allUsers)
{
    if (!userIdsToRemove.contains(u.Id))
    {
        usersToUpdate.Add(u);
    }
}
```

I get the following error: Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [List].contains(Id)
Why is my code complaining about contains()? Is there a way to optimize this code

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `List` [class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm) does not have a `contains` method. Use the `Set` [class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm) instead:

```
Set<Id> userIdsToRemove = new Set<Id>();
if (!userIdsToRemove.contains(u.Id)) { /* do stuff */ }
```

Comment: right on.  @user569925 - This is why I always suffix the name of my collection variables as either `....List`, `...Set`, or `....Map` so when I look at / edit the code I know which methods are available to use (given the absence of code complete in my version of the Force.com Eclipse IDE)

Comment: I tend to find the use of suffixes distasteful and use other conventions for that (e.g. `Map` is usually something like `keyToValue`, `parentToChildren`, etc.). However it is a good strategy if confusion is creeping in about which data type is in use.

Comment: Does it not seem utterly ludicrous that such an obvious method is missing?

Comment: @NickJ Yes, it does.

Answer (score 24):

Since so many people have viewed this question, I wanted to provide an updated answer to this for anybody who visits this question in 2018 & beyond: The upcoming version of Salesforce (Spring '18) does add the contains() method to List: [Spring '18 Release Notes: New and Changed Classes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_apex_new_classes_methods.htm)

> **contains(listElement)**
>
> Returns true if the list contains the specified element.

Comment: Caution:- This method only works in debug mode, for e.g if you setup debug log for current user it will work, but it will stop working as soon as you remove debug logs for current user or close developer console.  This is strange but true. I am testing in sandbox with API version 42.0

Comment: @SFIntegrator are you sure about that?  When you say it stops working do you mean it returns false? Or throws an exception?

Comment: @NSjonas Yes it returns false.

Comment: @SFIntegrator , Do you know if this issue is fixed or is it still happening.

Comment: To future viewers, see [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/224490/10382) for an explanation of why `List.contains()` can fail depending on what your debug logs are set to.

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001RXPlQAO&title=list-contains-fails-to-detect-element-match-when-input-param-is-an-sobject-id-field-it-succeeds-when-debug-logs-are-enabled worth checking as well! (and upvoting!)

Comment: It is working fine

Comment: It is happening for me again in 2020 in multiple orgs in APAC region

Answer (score 1):

Contains is the Set Class method not the list class.. as the query return the list . You need to convert list to set and then You can use the contains method..You use other comparison operator with the list..

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below in your code. This is just for reference.

```
List<String> city = new List<String>();
city.add('Nagpur');
city.add('Hyderabad');
city.add('Mumbai');
city.add('Indor');
city.add('Chennai');
city.add('Amravati');
city.sort();

Set<String> setCity = new Set<String>(city);
System.debug('Set City : '+setCity);
System.debug(setCity.contains('Amravati'));
```