# Bug in List.contains for Id data type?

Tags: apex

Am not doing anything fancy, just trying to use [contains](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm) method of list.

```
List<Id> myIdList = new List<Id>();
myIdList.add('0060E000008PdMk');

Id oppId ='0060E000008PdMk';   


System.debug(myIdList.contains(oppId)); //Returns false
```

To my surprise, I spent a few hours debugging and came with this problematic code. Are we not supposed to use contains for `List<Id>` ?

Changing the type from `List<Id>` to `List<String>` makes my code run, but I dont have any clue why it does?

Can anyone shed some light?

**UPDATE** : As per the suggestion of sfdcfox I have raised a case with SF support. Case number "19522568". I will keep you guys updated with the results.

**UPDATE 2** : Salesforce reached out to me for this,

A bug W-4884673 already exist for this issue. SF R&D team is working on the same. Known issue link for reference: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?Id=a1p3A000000AT9c

There isn't any ETA for this to be fixed, so the case will be closed as "bug fix submitted"

**UPDATE 3** : This has now been resolved

Comment: I'd be curious to see what happens if you debug the list itself, or debug `oppId == myIdList[0]`

Comment: oppId == myIdList[0] returned true.

Comment: Interesting that Apex using `.hashCode()` for contains differs from [Java List that uses `.equals()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2642709/54026)

Comment: According to the "known issue" cited in Update 2, above, this has been fixed in "Spring '19". However, we are seeing this issue on newly created scratch orgs.

Comment: Guess who is back - https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001RXPlQAO&title=list-contains-fails-to-detect-element-match-when-input-param-is-an-sobject-id-field-it-succeeds-when-debug-logs-are-enabled

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like this bug [System.hashCode broken on Id properties of SObjects?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82930/system-hashcode-broken-on-id-properties-of-sobjects) remains unfixed.

Diagnosis is made more confusing because of this [hashCode() is never called when adding to Maps and Sets](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46525/hashcode-is-never-called-when-adding-to-maps-and-sets) where the debug level determines if `hashCode` is called or not.

Comment: weird that it works fine when debug is finest. Is there a reason why it works with debug mode

Comment: Setting the debug level to FINEST uses `equals` to do the comparison instead of `hashCode`. The same Id will have different `HashCodes` in some cases - which causes the `contains` failure. This has been a bug in the platform for ~4 years now?

Comment: @RedDevil A guess is that the not calling hashCode was added to help isolate problems in bad hashCode implementations. But as it is not documented it does more harm than good IMHO.

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like it may be an edge case; it returns true in my org:

```
09:28:48.2 (4756791)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[7]|System.debug(ANY)
09:28:48.2 (4767250)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|true
09:28:48.2 (4775541)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[7]|System.debug(ANY)
```

Please consider submitting a bug if you have a valid reproduction that support can use. In the general case, you should be able to use contains as intended.

Comment: Can you confirm if it was same code you tried? I tried this on Sandbox S18 , My companies' prod org and my personal 10 mb dev org. Same behavior.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I tried your code, literally copy-pasted from your question, and it worked in my dev org.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal works in at least two sandboxes and two production orgs. It may be something that was fixed recently, or bugged recently. Please do log a case; it *should* work correctly.

Comment: I have raised a case now with SF support, Case number "19522568" , the only fear I have is they will close the case quoting "There is a workaround in place".  Lets hope for the best. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal If they dare do that, let me know. I'll DM the PM of Apex Code.

Comment: @sfdcfox What Apex code logging level are you using? I'm reproducing on NA64, which is currently on [Summer '18 Patch 11.11](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_releases_view?release=212000000).

Comment: @DanielBallinger I was running on the default SFDC_DeveloperConsole, which looks like it defaulted to FINEST Apex. I just changed it to None and set an assert, and the code now repros on NA3. So, in my case, was just a debugging red herring.

Comment: @sfdcfox: I have come across this weird thing today,
List.contains for the id list return true if the debug logs area assigned to running user OR the developer console is open for running user OR system.debug(idlist) statement is present before the if condition.
I have tried this on multiple orgs, same reproducible behavior.

Answer (score 5):

I can repo this on na37.

```
List<Id> myIdList = new List<Id>();
myIdList.add('0060E000008PdMk');

Id oppId ='0060E000008PdMk';   

System.assert(oppId == myIdList[0]); // true 
System.assert(myIdList.contains(oppId)); // false - assertion failed !!
```

Changing the types of the List and the variable to `String` causes this code to run as expected.

---

It looks like the HashCodes under the surface don't match up. This example casts our ids to objects, and calls `HashCode` on them, then compares them. They fail, despite the values being the same.

You can cause the `contains` to find the value by changing the debug level of "Apex Code" to `FINEST`. This (According to @KeithC) causes the comparison to not use `HashCode` and use `equals` instead, and results in a `true` value from `contains`.

```
List<Id> myIdList = new List<Id>();
// Added extra characters to ensure it wasnt something with 15/18 char ids 
myIdList.add(((Id)'0060E000008PdMkOIP'));

Id oppId = '0060E000008PdMkOIP';  

Integer oppHash = ((Object)oppId).hashCode();
Integer listHash = ((Object)myIdList[0]).hashCode();

System.assertEquals(oppHash, listHash); // !! Fails!! - hash values differ  

System.assert(oppId.equals(myIdList[0])); // true

// !! Setting debug APEXCODE to FINEST results in true 
System.assert(myIdList.contains(oppId)); // false
```

Comment: I tried that on EU12, works fine, exactly like @sfdcfox

Comment: I've reproduced this on CS52 too

Comment: Doesn't make sense, :/ Different implementation for different instances...

Comment: Check out the comments under this answer from earlier this year : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/203154/10382. Seems similar, may be playing a role (since the return false seems dead on with whats happening here)

Comment: Does turning on debug using finest fix this? No hashCode called in that case.

Comment: Yes ! It works without a problem with the APEX CODE debug level set to FINEST. I noticed the hashcodes were different as I was testing, but I chalked it up to the casting & them being different objects.