# Strange - select statement doesn't work with List<ID> and works with List<String>

Tags: apex, soql

In below code, we can observe that 'actionPlanTempList' contains an ID `'a076F00000uedBaQAI'`. Also `ap_Action_Plan_Task_Dependency__c` object also contains records for `Action_Plan_Template__c=a076F00000uedBa`. However 3rd Select statement returns nothing.

```
System.debug('actionPlanTempList - '+actionPlanTempList);
//returns: actionPlanTempList - (a076F00000uedBaQAI)


List<ap_Action_Plan_Task_Dependency__c> allldependencyList 
    = [Select ID, Action_Plan_Template__c, Dependent_Task__c, Dependent_On_Task__c From ap_Action_Plan_Task_Dependency__c]; 

System.debug('allldependencyList - '+allldependencyList);
//returns: allldependencyList - (ap_Action_Plan_Task_Dependency__c:{Id=a096F00002LKwSSQA1, Action_Plan_Template__c=a076F00000uedBa, Dependent_Task__c=a086F00002DtsfCQAR, Dependent_On_Task__c=a086F00002DtsfAQAR}, ap_Action_Plan_Task_Dependency__c:{Id=a096F00002LKwScQAL, Action_Plan_Template__c=a076F00000uedBa, Dependent_Task__c=a086F00002DtsfoQAB, Dependent_On_Task__c=a086F00002DtsfCQAR}, ap_Action_Plan_Task_Dependency__c:{Id=a096F00002LKwSIQA1, Action_Plan_Template__c=a076F00000uedBa, Dependent_Task__c=a086F00002DtsfBQAR, Dependent_On_Task__c=a086F00002DtsfAQAR}, ap_Action_Plan_Task_Dependency__c:{Id=a096F00002LKwShQAL, Action_Plan_Template__c=a076F00000uedBa, Dependent_Task__c=a086F00002DtsfoQAB, Dependent_On_Task__c=a086F00002Dtsf0QAB}, ap_Action_Plan_Task_Dependency__c:{Id=a096F00002LKwSXQA1, Action_Plan_Template__c=a076F00000uedBa, Dependent_Task__c=a086F00002DtsfoQAB, Dependent_On_Task__c=a086F00002DtsfBQAR})


List<ap_Action_Plan_Task_Dependency__c> dependencyList 
    = [Select ID, Action_Plan_Template__c, Dependent_Task__c, Dependent_On_Task__c From ap_Action_Plan_Task_Dependency__c 
       Where Action_Plan_Template__c IN :actionPlanTempList];

System.debug('dependencyList - '+dependencyList); 
//returns: dependencyList - ()
```

Interestingly - `actionPlanTempList` is List of IDs. When I change it to List of String it works as expected.

Why?

Edit 1:

On `ap_Action_Plan_Task_Dependency__c` Object, the field `Action_Plan_Template__c` is a formula field and also on Task Object, the field `Action_Plan_Template__c` is a formula field.

actionPlanTempList is being generated list this.

```
for(Task t:Trigger.New) { 
    actionPlanTempList.add(t.Action_Plan_Template__c); 
}
```

Comment: What is `Action_Plan_Template__c` and what is its type? How are you building `actionPlanTempList`?

Comment: @Mahmood it is custom object. This is how i am building the list. For(Task t:Trigger.New){       
            actionPlanTempList.add(t.Action_Plan_Template__c);
    }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bug in List.contains for Id data type?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224490/bug-in-list-contains-for-id-data-type)

Comment: Its a known bug, changing the debug level to finest will make your code work.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal it is not exactly the same(i.e. no problem with List.contains function) but is similar.

Comment: Hi @GaneshBhosle I belive its might look different But internally they all are affected by same SF bug. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?Id=a1p3A000000AT9c

Comment: Hi @PranayJaiswal My understaning is - The bug I am facing is not about methods of List object and I am facing this in Logs. The bug is about the behaviour of the SELECT statement, it works differently if list passed is of IDs and if list is of Strings.

Comment: Cool, lets see what community can answer. +1 for me

Comment: What is the data type of the formula field `Action_Plan_Template__c` on your objects? I would imagine it's a TEXT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments:

> On `ap_Action_Plan_Task_Dependency__c` Object, the field `Action_Plan_Template__c` is a **formula** field and also on `Task` Object, the field `Action_Plan_Template__c` is a **formula** field.

I would think that the data type of these formula fields are of type *TEXT* which signifies that these are not of type *Id* but *String*.

Here's my take - when you add the formula values to the `List<Id>`, the platform does not treat it as *Ids* based on the return type but *String*. However you are still able to add it in the list because the value is still a well constructed Id.

*(There does seem to be an issue and possibly related to what @Pranay has mentioned, where adding a valid String value for Id into `List<Id>` does not work, I have tried to explain later with a quick finding)*

This is the reason why your code works when you declare your `actionPlanTempList` as `List<String>`.

As a quick test, you can use the `getSObjectType()` method to verify that the value being added to the list is not actually an Id. So, where you are adding the formula field values in the iteration, if you put a debug statement as below:

```
for(Task t:Trigger.New) { 
    actionPlanTempList.add(t.Action_Plan_Template__c);    

    system.debug(t.Action_Plan_Template__c.getSobjectType());
}
```

You will get an error saying:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getSObjectType() from the type *String*

---

**UPDATE**

Seems like casting or parsing the string value into an *Id* type just doesn't work in the IN clause of the query. I had earlier thought it worked but when verified again, it simply ignores anything added in `List<Id>`.

It looks like unless and until the field being returned from the query is not of type *Id*, `List<Id>` just doesn't work in IN clause.

So let's say if there's a query as below where `mylookup__c` is a lookup field (Id), creating the list of Id and using it in SOQL will just work fine.

```
List<myobj__c> listOfObjs = [select id, name, mylookup__c from myobj__c];
List<Id> mylookupList = new List<Id>();
for(myobj__c m : listOfObjs) {
    mylookupList.add(m.mylookup__c);
}

// ONLY NOW List<Id> WORKS HERE
List<myobj__c> newlistOfObjs = [select id, name from myobj__c where mylookup__c IN :mylookupList]
```

---

Its just not clear as how in run-time, the IN clause in SOQL works where there's a difference in behavior when *String* values are added in `List<Id>` vs. the same values added in `List<String>`.

Comment: Wouldnt assigning a text to Id datatype will throw an exception?

Comment: Based on a quick test, could see it just worked fine, as long as it's a well constructed Id value, you can add it to a `List<Id>`

Comment: Yeah,, That means Id are valid, so is List<Id> and thus query should return results.

Comment: That's what is confusing as how the platform evaluates that at run-time. As it works on list of string but not on list of ids.

Comment: This is my theory from the bug found few days back, When using IN clause hashcode and equals methods are called for List<ID> as those methods are broken it returns inconsistent results.

Comment: Is it the same issue that you have mentioned in the comments above? Or there's another one?

Comment: Same Issue I tagged, https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224490/bug-in-list-contains-for-id-data-type