# Multiple OR (||) Conditions in If Statement

Tags: apex, trigger, if

Can anyone explain why the following If statement does not work with multiple OR conditions. The goal is when this trigger runs, if the user's Id who is updating the record is not equal to a specific Id, then an error is thrown. The If clause works only when I compare the current user's Id with a single specific Id.

```
    String currentUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();

    if (currentUserId != 'XXXXXXXXX' || currentUserId != 'YYYYYYYYY' || currentUserId != 'ZZZZZZZZZ') {
        Trigger.new[0].addError('Only specific users are able to change the Account Classification Field'); 
    }
```

{EDIT} FYI: I know I can accomplish this by using the following code, but I am curious as to why the OR operator is not working as I had expected.

```
    if (currentUserId != 'XXXXXXXXX') {
        if (currentUserId != 'YYYYYYYYY') {
            if (currentUserId != 'ZZZZZZZZZ') {
                Trigger.new[0].addError('Only specific users are able to change the Account Classification Field'); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

"OR" means "true if either value is true". If the ID is "XXXXXXXXX", for example, it will NOT be "YYYYYYYYY", therefore OR will result in a true value. You need to use "AND" (&&) instead, meaning "true only if both values are true."

---

Side note: It's not enough to just put an error on Trigger.new[0]; there may be multiple records in the trigger context, and this can result in a "too many retries" error during bulk data operations.

Comment: Maybe my logic is incorrect, but I believe do want "true if either [any] value is true" and not "true only if both values are true." Please correct me if I am wrong, but if I use the && operator than the error will be thrown only if the User's Id is equal to XXXXXXXXX, YYYYYYYYY, AND ZZZZZZZZZ?

Comment: Then use `==` instead of `!=` in your comparison.

Comment: That'd mean `If the user is EQUAL to X OR Y OR Z`. You have it written as `if the user is DIFFERENT to X OR Y OR Z`

Comment: @MaxGoldfarb You'll want to look at de Morgan's Laws. If the user Id must be one of three values, you would say "Id is equal to XXXXX OR YYYYY OR ZZZZZ".

Comment: Awesome thanks for your help guys, I really appreciate it, @sfdcfox using the && operator seems to satisfy my requirements from my brief testing. Again, really appreciate you guys/girls help!

Comment: @sfdcfox my apologies for the questions and again I rally appreciate your help but I wanted to thank you again for raising the bulk dml error risk, I believe I have solved that now as well. You are the best :)

Answer (score 3):

@sfdcfox is correct, Although I would do a

```
!( (new List<String>{'XXXX','YYYY','ZZZZ'}).contains(currentUserId) )
```

Chaining a bunch of Logical OR's gets messy, especially if you need to add to the list in the future. I would make a public static variable of it to describe the classes permission if you plan on using that permission group you have there in more than one place.

Comment: That's a really good idea, will probably do this. Thanks!

Comment: If you want also you could make a property of the class and say something like Class.UserIsInAdminGroup

Comment: I would look into this ticket if you are planning on using List<Id> https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224490/bug-in-list-contains-for-id-data-type. Theres a reason i use string because salesforce fixing things won't come in your or my lifetime

Answer (score 1):

In programming,

```
if (currentUserId != 'XXXXXXXXX' || currentUserId != 'YYYYYYYYY' || currentUserId != 'ZZZZZZZZZ') {}
```

means that, if at least any of the 3 conditions is TRUE, the full expression is TRUE.

For a currentUserId='XXXXXXXXX', the expression is evaluated as

> currentUserId != 'XXXXXXXXX'  ==> FALSE
> currentUserId != 'YYYYYYYYY'  ==> TRUE
> currentUserId != 'ZZZZZZZZZ'  ==> TRUE

So, for currentUserId='XXXXXXXXX', it adds the error `Only specific users are able to change the Account Classification Field`, which is not desirable.

It can be explained by De Morgan's Law.

> Not (A and B) is the same as Not A or Not B.
>
> Not (A or B) is the same as Not A and Not B.

In your case,

> currentUserId NOT ('XXXXXXXXX' OR 'YYYYYYYYY' OR 'ZZZZZZZZZ')

which can be written as

> currentUserId NOT 'XXXXXXXXX' **AND**  currentUserId NOT 'YYYYYYYYY' **AND** currentUserId NOT 'ZZZZZZZZZ'

Answer (score 1):

While your logic will always return true because the value is always not one of the three values, correcting this code by inverting `||` to `&&` would be missing the point that there is a better way to filter logic so it is specific to a subset of users. The two most ideal ways to code for this so that it is configurable are `Custom Permissions` and `Hierarchy Custom Settings`.

**Custom Permissions**

1. Create a `Custom Permission` named e.g. `CanDoOperationX`.
2. Create a `Permission Set` which contains only this permission.
3. Assign this `Permission Set` to each `User` in your whitelist.
4. Update your condition to check `FeatureManagement.checkPermission('CanDoOperationX')`

**Hierarchy Custom Setting**

This option doesn't make as much sense unless you have other user specific overrides for this functionality, but it is certainly viable.

1. Create a `Hierarchy Custom Setting` named e.g. `MyTriggerSettings`.
2. Add a `Checkbox` field named e.g. `Can_Do_Operation_X__c`.
3. Create a new record in this setting for each `User` in your whitelist.
4. Update your condition to check `$MyTriggerSettings__c.getInstance().Can_Do_Operation_X__c`.