# How to declare static literal

Tags: apex, custom-object, enum

I have a piece of code:

```
if (testClone.testprocess__c !=null) {
                    if (testIteration.Key__c == 'ut') {
                        req.Status__c = 'testing';
                        testIteration.Status__c = 'active';
                    }
                }
```

Key__c is a field on a custom object and has certain values like `'ut', 'ml'` etc. In the IF condition above I want to filter for all the different keys in the field and mark the status, meaning `if (testIteration.Key__c == 'ut') || if (testIteration.Key__c == 'ml')` & so on..

Can I use enum and add the keys to it, something like below:

```
public enum Key { UT, ML, RG, WB }
public static Map<Key, String> LABELS = new Map<Key, String>{
    Key.UT => 'ut',
    Key.ML => 'ml',
    Key.RG => 'rg',
    Key.WB => 'wb'
};
```

And then filter it in the IF condition above, if yes, how to fetch the enum keys ?
Or
How can I avoid adding multiple OR conditions to my IF above and still be able to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you make a List and then see if the value of `Key__c` is contained in the List?

```
private final List<String> keys = new List<String>{'ut','ml','rg','wb'};

//some code

if (keys.contains(testIteration.Key__c)) {
    req.Status__c = 'testing';
    testIteration.Status__c = 'active';     
}
```

Comment: how can I use something like Switch, like mentioned by Sergio, for a particular key and change the status. For List I dont see any method that works like switch.

Comment: @Sfdcnewuser Do you need to do something differently depending on each key? For instance do you need to set the status differently depending if the key is `ut` or `ml` or something else?

Comment: yes that is what I intend to do @Arthlete

Comment: @Sfdcnewuser In this case you will have to go with a switch statement just as Sergio recommended. You will have to write down each `when` block for the switch separately. A List wouldn't be useful in that case. Is there something about his example that is unclear to you?

Comment: I am trying to learn ways of using list and was wondering if I could do switching between list keys values for certain type of conditions. I think I got my answer! thank you.

Comment: A list wouldn't be appropriate to combine with a switch statement. Even if you were to iterate over the values in the list you still need to specify what the value for the status would be for each value of the list. In other words you can't just iterate over the list's values because you have to do something different for each value.

Comment: @Sfdcnewuser have you thought about using custom metadata for your scenario? That can really shorten your code and if you have to change things in the future for your "keys" you won't have to touch your code.

Comment: I used custom labels to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I would take the approach of @Arthlete, but having a Set instead of a list, since the contains method, although documented, does not work properly por the List type.

Keep in mind that probably you do not need a map, since, if you have an ENUM like that one, you can get what you want by "key.UT.name()"

[https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_enum.htm#:~:text=An%20enum%20is%20an%20abstract,can%20define%20your%20own%20enum.&text=This%20method%20returns%20the%20values,of%20the%20same%20Enum%20type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_enum.htm#:%7E:text=An%20enum%20is%20an%20abstract,can%20define%20your%20own%20enum.&text=This%20method%20returns%20the%20values,of%20the%20same%20Enum%20type).

Comment: I've never had a problem using the `contains()` method of the List class. What problems have you encountered with it? Can you share an article/source so I can read about it.

Comment: There is this existing thread discussing about it:: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96702/list-contains-in-not-working

Update: It seems that, at some point, they fixed all the issues that it presented, so nowdays it could be used indistincly with List or Set I guess

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to have a `switch` statement

```
switch on (testIteration.Key__c) {
    when 'ut' {
        req.Status__c = 'testing';
        testIteration.Status__c = 'active';
    } when 'ml', 'rg' { // example with more than one value matching
        req.Status__c = 'xxx';
        testIteration.Status__c = 'active';
    }
    ...
    when else {
        // actions to take if it does not match any value
    }
}
```

If you decide to go with the `enum` approach, remember that you don't need to put `Key.` before the `UT` and so on, because apex is clever enough to know that you are "switching" on an enum and knows which enum is behind.